# Combining selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two click events as follows:

```
$($('[id^="tab"]')).live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});

$($('[id^="home"]')).live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Is it possible to combine this into one click even as the only difference is "home" and "tab"?

Comment: Just as a general note, taken from the jQuery documentation: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`. I believe this is due to memory issues with `.live()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, simply divide them by `,`:

```
$('[id^="tab"], [id^="home"]').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: For negating CSS selectors, list them in one quoted selector. Example: `$('[id^="tab"], [id^="home"]')` -> http://jsfiddle.net/yUYVh/2/
And please, don't vote down asking for support.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not reflected in your answer :) and I didn't vote it down for support ... I voted it down because the answer did not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('[id^="home"], [id^="tab"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="tab"], [id^="home"]').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yUYVh/3/